# Install and use PostgreSQL 9.3 on Amazon EC2

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, postgresql-9.3

I'm having a problem with an Amazon Linux (CentOs based) instance when trying to install the latest stable Postgres (version 9.3).

That version doesn't ships in the main repositories of that distro and I tried some of the RPM's that are available in the [Postgres download site](http://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php#pg93). CentOs and Fedora versions didn't worked, since they complained about the distro I'm using not to be the one they're made to. The Red Hat .rpm worked well and I could see the new packages available to yum.

I used the following:

```
wget http://yum.postgresql.org/9.3/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-redhat93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh pgdg-redhat93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm
```

So, I installed the Postgres packages of the version I'm interested in:

```
yum install postgresql93 postgresql93-devel postgresql93-server
```

So far, so good. Everything installed beatifully (just a php package conflicted, but I blew it up).

As said in every blog and help page, I initialized the database. For me, there is a need to change the PORT, so I did it in `/etc/init.d/postgresql-9.3` script, changing the port to 5552, that is available in this box. To initialize and start the server, nothing new:

```
service postgresql-9.3 initdb 
service postgresql-9.3 start
```

(the name of the service has the version, differently from the service installed from the mainstream amazon repositories)

It just works. I have no sign of problem until I tried to connect using `psql` utility:

```
[root@local]# su - postgres
-bash-4.1$ psql 
psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
```

As usual, I also can't do it with root, but with the user "postgres" it seems reasonable that the role at least should have been created.

I can't use `createdb` for the same strange reason. I've been receiving the same error for any operation I try in the bin folder that could interact with the database. For that, Im stuck with a "working" database but no user able to connect to it.

When searching around the tips I could find are always related to a user trying to connect using the **root** user and the solution is to use **postgres** user and I'm doing it, as you saw.

This is a problem that just happened when trying the version 9.3. When I tried the repository package (that is still 9.2) it worked just fine. I could connect and test the database normally.

Before this package I tried to compile Postgres from source, but the hell of dependencies just didn't let me go.

Is there any other adjust I might be missing, some package that is needed or even a guess you could share to help me solve this issue?

Comment: It is not clear which of those commands you executed as root and which you execute as ec2-user.  And `service postgresql-9.3` is not in itself a legal command, it must have had a ` start` after it?

Comment: Everything that was not specified to have been run as "postgres" was runned as "root". The service was a typo. Just corrected it.

Comment: Since you changed the port of the server from the default, you need to specify that non-default port when you execute psql.  (The error message you get suggests that *some* instance of PostgreSQL is running on the default port, just not the instance you want--but how did it get there?)

Comment: This makes sense. I'm gonna try ASAP.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue than you, after installing Postgresql on centOS by using yum. The thing is that Postgresql comes with a built-in user called `postgres`, which you should use to perform the first login. So, just try with:

```
su - postgres
psql
```

An then, you can create databases, users, and so on.
Hope this helps!

Comment: I would add that before I needed to put sudo -i This is my console: [ec2-user@ip-172-30-0-245 worthy.master.spec]$ sudo -i
[root@ip-172-30-0-245 ~]# su - postgres
Last login: Mon Jul 10 09:32:50 UTC 2017 on pts/0
-bash-4.2$ psql
psql (9.6.3)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#

Answer (score 0):

I think you already caught the problem: all operations need "postgres" user, which is a user setup by postgresql syetem as the admin for database. root user can't do this.

One of the way, from my previous experience, is: trying to restart the service (sudo service postgresqlxxx restart). If there is something wrong, the restart process will report error.

As I said, this user is admin of database, and you can't get around of it. If all of those don't work, then just reinstall it using "sudo yum install "